# How to apply page css to a polymer component

Tags: html, css, polymer

I want my polymer component to use styles from 'normal' stylesheet. So I added  shim-shadowdom to the style and /deep/ to the class, like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style shim-shadowdom>
      .mylink /deep/  {color: orange;}
    <style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-link></my-link>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then component:

```
<polymer-element name="my-link">
   <a class="mylink" href="#">xxx</a>
</polymer-element>
```

But this doesn't work neither in  chrome - the link still has its usual color  - no in ff and ie - the links are orange there, but they are orange even without /deep/ or shim-shadowdom.

The question - what am I doing wrong here?

Polymer version - 0.5.5.

PS: except styling, polymer works as expected - all components are shown up, ajax sends its requests and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need `my-link /deep/ .mylink`

Edit: Also, surround the `<a>` with a `<template>` element.  **Make sure your element is imported**!

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it! I really misunderstood /deep/ syntax so polymer has nothing to do with my problem. The only thing which is worth adding is that to apply style page-wide "body /deep/ .style {..." could be more handy.

Comment: And one more thing  - the reason style was applied in IE and FF is "Because polyfilling the styling behaviors of Shadow DOM is difficult, Polymer has opted to favor practicality and performance over correctness. For example, the polyfill’s do not protect Shadow DOM elements against document level CSS." (https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/styling.html#handling-scoped-styles)

Comment: @user656449 No problem!  I'm here to help.  If you need me, just ask :D